# Creating a simple neural network on Tensorflow by means of Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I want to create a simple neural network based on the example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/nn_sample. Is it possible to create this with the help on Tensorflow only with Android tools on Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this folder https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/nn_sample/app/src/main/cpp

simple_model.h is the model trained in Tensorflow before creating the Android project. Now the model likes black-box, get input and predict output only, if you want to build your own model, try this tutorial (All steps from training, evaluating, prediction to deploy onto Android):

https://medium.com/@elye.project/applying-tensorflow-in-android-in-4-steps-to-recognize-superhero-f224597eb055

Answer (score 0):

Affirmative. You can use `TensorFlow Lite` on Android, it's an open source deep learning framework which helps to compress and deploy models to a mobile or embedded application. It basically can take models as input and then deploys and interpret and perform resource-conserving optimizations for mobile applications. The `NNAPI` of Android NDK can interface with TFLite easily too. This [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/) contains gesture, image, object & speech detection and classification example implementations on Android with Java using TFLite.